# Why I can't parse the response in Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy and using it to scrape data from the Lazada website. I have got the 200 HTTP message meaning the response is successfully return. But I can't parse the response although the xpath query is correct. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

This is the code:

```
import scrapy

class LazadaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'lazada'
allowed_domains = ['lazada.com.my']
start_urls = ['https://lazada.com.my/catalog/?q=books/']

def parse(self, response):
    all_products = response.xpath('//div[@class="c2prKC"]') 
    print(len(all_products))
```

[the result showing 0 for the length of all_products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cgD8.png)
And the result is shown in the picture.

**UPDATE**: I did try to get the data stored in the javascript or using selenium to mimick a human browsing behaviour, however I will get blocked CAPTCHA after trying scraping for one time and then I need to wait for a 15 minute so that I can scrape the second time. Can anyone help me?

[the Captcha I faced after scraping lazada for one time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UqMu.png)

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try accessing the web through scrapy shell in terminal to catch the response, after that you can use the view(response) to open the browser and setup your xpath or css selector

```
scrapy shell https://lazada.com.my/catalog/?q=books/  # Access the web through scrapy
view(response)                                        # View cached web on browser
```

**Update** :
It seems lazada is using dynamic content to load the item (the item is loaded and rendered using javascript after the page is loaded), that means that you will need another module to crawl the web, try using selenium, scrapy-splash or requests-html.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Really appreciate it and will try it later.

Comment: I have tried response.css("div#root div.ant-row div.ant-row div"), but it still give null, is the css correct?

Comment: the items ini lazada is rendered using javascript after the page is loaded, you can check this by printing the response text from scrapy. To crawl this kind of web site  you will need another module to render the javascript, you can try using selenium, requests-html or scrapy splash, or you can inspect the page in browser and try to get the xhr request from the page itself to get the source of the data if it exist

Comment: first, thank you for your comments. I did try selenium, but somehow I will get blocked by CAPTCHA after a few times trying...

Comment: The text is loaded from JSON from a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

The item is loaded and rendered using javascript after the page is loaded.

[shown item from view-source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av4fi.png)

[shown item from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqEds.jpg)

How to get item from response?

```
data_str = response.css('script')[3].re_first('window.pageData=({.+})')
```

Comment: firstly very thank you for the comments, I did try it out before, however, it works only the first time, then I will be blocked by the CAPTCHA, can u help me? I'm still stuck since last week.

Comment: what kind of captcha?

Comment: a page contained slider

Comment: i can't find any articles teaching to bypass the anti-scraping tools in lazada

Comment: Here is one article to bypass slide captcha: https://medium.com/the-innovation/how-to-solve-slide-captcha-problem-using-machine-learning-method-340f54f8a32f

Comment: thank you, btw may i know if you face the same blocking when trying to scrape for more than 1 time?

Comment: Great to hear that. Do u mind to share the whole code to me to see if it helps me? Thank you.

Comment: scrapy shell https://lazada.com.my/catalog/?q=books/ 
data_str = response.css('script')[3].re_first('window.pageData=({.+})')

Comment: I have tried it. The result is the same. I get the value when I scraped it for the first time. But then it returns none for the second time onwards

Comment: Yes, you are right!  Maybe you should try some anti-baned strategy like disable cookie, use the proxy, switch useragent and so on. Finally, bypass the captcha is not a hard job.

Comment: So sad to say I have tried to write a script in selenium to bypass the CAPTCHA, but it fails. Anyway, thanks for your help. Gooday